# Will Stacked Symmetra's Turrets Stop Genji from Swift Striking Past Them?

Tags: overwatch

Symmetra's turrets add a slow effect when firing on enemy players, which stack the more turrets that are firing on a player.

When defending on the Anubis Temple (Egypt) map, I like to place turrets in the righthand room at the main twin gates leading to objective A, because this room is often used for flanking by the enemy team.

#### Question

If I place all 6 of Symmetra's turrets in the room, would an enemy Genji still be able to Swift Strike past them, or will they slow down the Swift Strike enough that the Genji bascially becomes immobile?

Comment: Regardless of the answer to this, don't put all your turrets together. That's a great way to get them blown up so you have zero turrets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is, even though Swift Strike is relatively quick, Symmetra's sentries will not lock on until Genji has exited Swift Strike, and is still in range of your sentries.

So to answer your question, if the Genji swift strikes past your sentries, and ends in a spot that is out of range, the sentries will not stop it.

Comment: I've heard that Junkrat's trap will actually pull players into it if they try to jump over it, so this also explains how a Genji ended up Swift Striking past that as well. I guess Swift Strike gives Genji a sort of limited invulnerability or immunity to status effects for the brief duration that it's in effect.